# running script containing sudo in cron

Tags: linux, unix, sudo, shell-scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
value=$(<man.txt)
echo "$value"

if [ "$value" == "true" ]; then
    echo "startedif_manthan"
      ps -ef|grep sym |awk '{ print $2 }'|sudo  xargs kill -9;
      sleep 30;
    sudo sh /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin/sym --port 8082 --server;
fi
```

I need to run above script in cron. Will it execute in cron without password?

Any suggestions?

Comment: We really do prefer that people try and do things for themselves rather than just dump code on us and say make it work. You should try to do it yourself and more importantly try and figure it our yourself - it's much more productive for everyone in the long run.

Comment: _Will it execute in cron without password?_ Try it. What happens when you run the script? Does it prompt for a password? Show us the output. Show us relevant entries in the logfiles.

Comment: [Better answer for the same question](http://superuser.com/a/551967/235231) and [another duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869523/running-script-containing-sudo-in-cron)

Answer (score 1):

If your script is run without prompted a password is entirely up to your `/etc/sudoers` file and which user this cron-script is run as.

If the cron-script is run as `myuser`, you can have the following entry in `/etc/sudoers`

```
myuser ALL=NOPASSWD: /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin/sym
```

I am not sure how sudo works when running the script with `sh` first, so you might want to make `/var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin/sym` executable and replace this:

```
sudo sh /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin/sym --port 8082 --server;
```

with this

```
sudo /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin/sym --port 8082 --server;
```